# Bind a checkbox to a plain string in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

In my viewmodel i have tons of checkboxes bound to plain strings:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="CODE" data-bind="checked: itemValue" />
```

Until now, i'm using an observable array to resolve the true/false value of the checkbox to the value that i need:

```
var viewModel = {
    itemValue: ko.observableArray()
};
```

Which is the simplest and shortest way, if there is one,  to bind a checkbox to a string value without the need to reference it as `itemValue[0]` ?

What i need is the string value if checked, null if unchecked.

Due to the large amount of observables in my viewmodel, i would avoid  to use tons of conditions like `if(itemValue) ...`

Fiddle using an observableArray: https://jsfiddle.net/wu470qup/

Answer (score 0):

If you want effortless markup, you'll have to keep track of the checkboxes you want to render in your viewmodel. Here's the easiest example:

`allValues` is a regular array of strings. Each of these strings will get a checkbox. `itemValues` is an observable array of the strings that have a checked checkbox. `correctedValues` is a computed array with `null` for each unchecked box, and a string for each checked one.

Notice that I use `$data` to refer to the current string value in the `foreach`.

```js
var allValues = ["CODE", "ANOTHER_VAL"];
var itemValues = ko.observableArray();
var correctedValues = ko.computed(function() {
  var all = allValues;
  var checked = itemValues();

  return all.map(function(val) {
    return checked.indexOf(val) === -1 ? null : val;
  });
});

var viewModel = {
  allValues: allValues,
  itemValues: itemValues,
  correctedValues: correctedValues
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: allValues -->
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.itemValues, checkedValue: $data" />
  <span data-bind="text: $data"><span/>
</label>
<!-- /ko -->
<pre  data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

A more elegant approach would be to create viewmodels for each checkbox. For example:

```
var CheckboxItem = function() {
  this.label = ko.observable("CODE");
  this.checked = ko.observable(false);
  this.id = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.checked() ? this.label() : null;
  }, this);
};
```

With the HTML template:

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked" />
   <input data-bind="value: label" />
</label>
```

Then, in the parent viewmodel, you can store an observable array of `CheckBoxItem`s and have a computed array that holds all `id` properties.

Comment: I appreciate your help, really, but my viewmodel is deeply nested and moreover there are approx. ~80 components - so in my situation your proposal of a flat definition of the values is not desiderable. I search a minimalistic solution with less code & bloating as possible.

Comment: Hmm I don't think I really understand your usecase then. Something more like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ro2zn0hp/

Comment: Something that my vm JSON export looks like {"itemValue":"CODE"} and not {"itemValue":["CODE"]} and i can reference it as itemValue and not itemValue[0] - think easy as an input type=radio without the need to display two options